# Please help me with a router backend

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I have written a small module that has a page on the backend. On a test server it works fine (it works on windows). Once installed on the Battle Server (FreeBSD), while trying to go to the page of the module have a 404 error.

The first thing that came to mind, it's case letters (as developed for Windows).

The configuration of the router is:
config.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <ZM_Background before="Mage_Adminhtml">ZM_Background_Adminhtml</ZM_Background>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <background translate="title" module="background">
            <title>Media</title>
            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items translate="title" module="background">
                    <title>Manage backgrounds</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/zm_background</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </background>
    </menu>
</config>
```

In this configuration, I have a 404
but if I change the register on line

```
<action>adminhtml/ZM_Background</action>
```

In this case, the URL in the administration panel module has caps that are not very nice.
Help to understand what files you need to check for the register that would fix it.
Thanks.

so, too, is working

```
<action>adminhtml/ZM_background</action>
```

Comment: Please add your filenames with paths (it's about directories and files lettercases probably).

Comment: Try changing your `ZM_Background` tag in `<modules>` to all lowercase.

Comment: @Joseph. Thanks, but it does not work(. So, too, the way work
<action> adminhtml / ZM_background </ action>

Comment: @versedi, I make a screenshot and will update the post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, but the cause until the end and did not understand ...
If you change the path to the controller other than the namespace of the module, the router is working properly.

For example, if

```
<action>adminhtml/zm_background</action>
```

replace to

```
<action>adminhtml/test_background</action>
```

and change the way

```
ZM\Background\controllers\Adminhtml\ZM\BackgroundController.php
```

on

```
ZM\Background\controllers\Adminhtml\Test\BackgroundController.php
```

so the controller starts working normally, with small letters...

Maybe it's due to the fact that the use namespace twice, or two uppercase characters in the address or something like that ... but a solution is found, and it suits me)